# User can't create objects in the page

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I made a program where users can keep track of their expenses by entering them into the system after creating their own account. The system requires users to fill in four fields: **customer**, **category**, **price**, and **month**. I would like the first field (**customer**) to automatically populate with the **username** of the logged-in user, so that users don't have to choose from all available customers.

However, I encountered an issue where users are unable to create objects in the system. I can only create objects through the admin dashboard. When I try to create an object on the page, it throws an error message saying,

```py
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at / User has no customer.
```

I suspect this problem is related to the fact that users are added in the ***authentication and authorization*** section under **Users** in the admin page, instead of being created under **Customers** by my app, alongside the **Finance** section where the objects are stored.

To summarize my two main issues:

1. I want the first field to automatically populate with the username of the logged-in user.
2. I want users to be able to create objects directly from the page, as they could in the past when this issue didn't occur.

Thank you so much for your help.

models.py:

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.name #I don't now if it's correct


class Finance(models.Model):
    expenses_category = [
        ("Saving", "Saving"),
        ("Food", "Food"),
        ("Bills", "Bills"),
        ("Rent", "Rent"),
        ("Extra", "Extra"),
    ]

    expenses_month = [
        ("January", "January"),
        ("February", "February"),
        ("March", "March"),
        ("April", "April"),
        ("May", "May"),
        ("June", "June"),
        ("July", "July"),
        ("August", "August"),
        ("September", "September"),
        ("October", "October"),
        ("November", "November"),
        ("December", "December"),
    ]

    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=expenses_category, max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    month = models.CharField(choices=expenses_month, max_length=200)
```

views.py:

```py
@csrf_exempt
def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                # form.instance.user = request.user
                user = form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

                group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
                user.groups.add(group)

                messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)

                return redirect('login')

        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'app_finance/register.html', context)


def loginPage(request):
    username = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        username = request.user.customer
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Username or password incorrect.')

        context = {}
        return render(request, 'app_finance/login.html', context)


def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')


def userPage(request):
    return render(request, 'app_finance/user.html')


@login_required(login_url='login')
def homeView(request):
    # customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk) (not sure#)
    username = None
    items = Finance.objects.filter(customer_id=request.user.id)
    form = FinanceForm(initial={'customer': User})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.user.customer
        form = FinanceForm(request.POST)  # initial={'customer': user}
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = FinanceForm()
        return render(request, 'app_finance/home.html', {'form': form, 'items': items})
```

forms.py:

```py
class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class FinanceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Finance
        fields = '__all__'
```

templates/home.html:

```html
<div>
    <span>Hello, {{ request.user }}</span> <br>
    <span><a class="hello-msg" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></span>
</div>


<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <!-- {{ form }} -->

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h1>Expenses</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Month</th>
                </tr>
                {% for i in items %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ i.customer }}</td>
                        <td>{{ i.category }}</td>
                        <td>{{ i.price }}</td>
                        <td>{{ i.month }}</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="">Update</a></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Which one of these model do you want to create in html form?

Comment: can you please add the code of User model also?

Comment: @Bamagujen_Bahaushe. it would be the Finance Model. I was thinking to exclude 'customer' in FinanceForm, so the user doesn't have to select its username, but i leave it that way so i could check if its making the Form properly, selecting the user who logged in, so far it doesn't do it

Comment: @DivyaPrakash It is from Django's user authentication system, so it's not in my code. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/

Comment: Does the user have to create a `Finance` model based on what is created from a `Customer` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution i found and worked perfect too.
I made 2 changes:

1. views.py:

```
    @login_required(login_url='login')
def homeView(request):
    items = Finance.objects.filter(customer=request.user).order_by(Cast('month', IntegerField())).reverse()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FinanceForm(request.POST, request=request)  # Pass the request object to the form
        if form.is_valid():
            finance_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            finance_obj.customer = request.user
            finance_obj.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = FinanceForm(request=request)  # Pass the request object to the form

    context = {'form': form, 'items': items}
    return render(request, 'app_finance/home.html', context)
```

2. forms.py

```
    class FinanceForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')  # Retrieve the request object
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['customer'].initial = self.request.user
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said that on your comment:

> it would be the Finance Model. I was thinking to exclude 'customer' in FinanceForm, so the user doesn't have to select its username, but I leave it that way so I could check if it is making the Form properly, selecting the user who logged in, so far it doesn't do it.

Allowing user to select himself while creating model is unintelligent, because someone may use other user to create them an object of the `Finance` model, to fix these issues, you have to change your `FinanceForm` by removing `'__all__'` and specify the field you want user to see:

```py
class FinanceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Finance
        fields = ['month', 'price', 'category']
```

While you are saying: you want to submit a `Finance` model, you did not include the view that does that in your question. Therefore, you can use either a function-based view or a class-based view to do so.

Using Function base view:

```py
def create_finance(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        price = request.POST['price']
        month = request.POST['month']
        category = request.POST['category']
        form = FinanceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_finance_object = Finance.objects.create(customer=request.user, price=price, month=month, category=category)
            new_finance_object.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = FinanceForm()
    return render(request, 'create_finance.html', {'form':form})
```

you can use Class Base View:

```py
from django.views.generic import CreateView 

class CreateFinance(CreateView):
    model = Finance
    form_class = FinanceForm
    template_name = 'create_finance.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.customer = self.request.user
        return super(CreateFinance, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I found another solution too, I'll share it.